# user data migration from xp to windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp

Do you know any tool/software s to migrate the data from an windows xp user profile to a windows 7 user profile? Besides, the "documents" part, the software that we would like to cover is Outlook, Internet Explorer, firefox and thunderbird?

Preferably, GPL software of course.

BR
christian

PS : Please, I'm looking for a software not how to do it I can figure that out mostly. I just would like to avoid scripting the actions that others should have already done... (I hope ;-)).

Answer (score 1):

The `Files and Settings Transfer Wizard` is not supported on Windows 7, but you can installed the Windows 7 equivalent on the XP machine (`Windows Easy Transfer`), run that to create a .MIG file on an external hard drive, and then run `Windows Easy Transfer` again on the Windows 7 machine, point it at the file, select which accounts you want to import (and create new local accounts to match, if required), and away you go.

I've used it to migrate 2 users to new Win7 laptops in the last week, and so far, so painless!

Can also be used over a network, or via a special cable (USB-A to USB-A, I think), but the external hard drive solution worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers something as a part of Windows, on XP it's called `Files and Settings Transfer wizard`, not sure about the name on Win7 though and can't check right now.

This tool is for few users, but there is also the User State Migration Tool 4.0, which is part of the [Windows 7 AIK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343(WS.10).aspx) (Automated Installation Kit).